# Subir archivo en la misma página

Tags: php

Estoy subiendo un archivo **csv** en una página llamada **procesar**, el problema es que me hace un POST y me envía a otra página y me muestra el resultado de **¡La importación del archivo se subió satisfactoriamente!**, pero yo necesito que eso me lo muestre en la misma página.

Éste es el código que tengo.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(function(){
    $("#btnEnviar").click(function(){
        $("#cuerpoPagina").load('ejemplo.php',$("#frmAsignar").serialize());
    })
});

    function subirArchivoExcel()
    {
        if (document.frmSubirArchivo.excel.value == "") 
        {
        alert("¡Error!. ¡Debe subir un archivo!");
        document.frmSubirArchivo.excel.focus();
        return false;
        }

        document.frmSubirArchivo.action="ejemplo.php";
        document.frmSubirArchivo.submit();
    }
</script>
<?php

echo '<form name="frmSubirArchivo" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="1" id="colorTabla">
            <tr>
                <td aling="center" id="TituloVerde">Archivo excel</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="file" name="excel" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Subir Archivo" onclick="subirArchivoExcel();" ></td>
            </tr>
    </form>';
```

Comment: Este código que estas mostrando es tu archivo procesar.php? Y donde esta ese mensaje del que estas hablando?

Comment: Ahora estoy mas confundido. Que es #cuerpoPagina y #frmAsignar? Podrias revisar el articulo de como incluir un [mcve] y [edit] tu pregunta para que este un poco mas entendible?

Comment: ¿Añado todo el código? porque de ahí ya va la parte lógica.

Comment: Voy a ponerte una prueba de concepto aunque no me base completamente en tu código que acabas de editar (me pillaste redactando y depurando).

Comment: Sigo sin entender cuál de todo eso es procesar.php, y que es #cuerpoPagina y #frmAsignar, como bien dice Kenny

Comment: He expuesto en mi respuesta algunos puntos que deberías tener en cuenta para que tu aplicación funcione. Espero que sean de ayuda.

Comment: Ese código se llama **procesar.php** (se está llamando a si mismo), **cuerpoPagina** = es un script que dice que cargue dentro de la misma página el contenido (pero como ven, me funciona en todas menos en ésta) y **#frmAsignar** es la asignación que se le da al form para que lo lea el script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la mejor opción es usar ajax para este tipo de casos, le envias el arhivo a "procesar.php", si todo sale bien, imprimes en tu "procesar.php" un json_encode("¡La importación del archivo se subió satisfactoriamente!"); y con ajax lo muestras en tu misma pagina

si tu "procesar.php" responde con un success tendria que devolver el mensaje en formato json y mostrarlo en un div cuyo id puede ser "mostrar_resultado"

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btnEnviar', function() {
 var excel = document.getElementByName("excel").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "procesar.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            excel: excel
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#mostrar_resultado').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿Has probado este código? ¿Estás seguro que envía el archivo?

Comment: ¿Ese $.ajax({ qué es?

Comment: ¿Esa respuesta va dentro del **<script>**?

Comment: no he probado el codigo, solo di un ejemplo de como podria ser, para eso tengo que tener el archivo procesar.php para probarlo, y en respuesta a la pregunta si va dentro del script, si va ahi dentro...

Comment: AJAX es una técnica que se utiliza para crear cambios en la pagina sin necesidad de recargarla.

Comment: Es que el código que pasé que está completo se llama **procesar.php**

Comment: Ya probé el script y no me da la función al botón **subir archivo**

Comment: tenes que descargar jquery o usar este CDN en tu archivo html,<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: tienes que ponerlo antes de que se cierre el body

Answer (score 1):

Tu `input` tiene ya configurado un evento `onclick`:

```
<input type="button" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar"
  value="Subir Archivo" onclick="subirArchivoExcel();" >
```

Luego vuelves a asociar el evento `click` a él:

```
$("#btnEnviar").click(function(){
```

Pero se ejecutarán ambos. La función `subirArchivoExcel` realiza el envío del formulario, así que da igual que se ejecute algo que modifique el DOM sin cambiar de página, el envío del formulario forzará al carga de una nueva página.

Además, la función [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) permite el envío de datos sencillo, pero `$("#frmAsignar").serialize()` no es capaz de serializar el contenido de una imagen.

Como puedes ver la funcionalidad de [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) se reduce a la interpretación de campos `<input>`, `<textarea>` y `<select>`:

> Note: Only "[successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. **Data from file select elements is not serialized.**

El [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input) de tipo `button` no hace nada por defecto, en mi ejemplo lo cambiaré por un tipo [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit).

Lo que haré será agregar un evento `submit` al formulario para interceptar su envío, en vez de la pulsación del botón. Durante el envío usaré una instancia de [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) para permitir el envío del archivo a través de XHR.

Por último has solicitado que en el mismo PHP se reciba el archivo, por lo que te he puesto una prueba de concepto de cómo detectar correctamente la recepción del archivo y averiguar si ocurrió algún error en el proceso.

Tras intercambiar opiniones y datos en el chat el resultado final es:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['excel']['error'])) {
    switch($_FILES['excel']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            if (preg_match('#\.csv#i', $_FILES['excel']['name']) === 0) {
                die('Extensión de archivo debe ser ".csv"');
            }
            mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db('pruebas') or die(mysql_error());

            $fecha      = date('Y-m-d');
            $hora       = time("HH:MM:SS");
            $carpeta    = "Registro_2/";
            $excel      = $fecha."-".$hora."-".$_FILES['excel']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], $carpeta . $excel);
            $fp = fopen($carpeta . $excel, "r");

            /* Arreglos para evitar inyección SQL y obtener la fecha de manera más elegante */
            function filtrar_sql(&$campo) {
                $campo = mysql_real_escape_string($campo);
            }
            setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8');

            /* Sacamos los primeros 7 (1 en mis pruebas) registros, son los títulos */
            for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ";");
            /* Número de filas insertadas correctamente */
            $insertadas = 0;
            while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ";")) {
                $fecha = strptime($data[0], '%A, %d de %B de %Y %H:%M');
                $fechaReal = ($fecha['tm_year'] + 1990) . "-" . $fecha['tm_mon'] . "-" .$fecha['tm_mday'];
                $hora = $fecha['tm_hour'] . ":" .$fecha['tm_min'];
                /* ¡¡MUY IMPORTANTE PARA EVITAR INYECCIÓN SQL !! */
                array_walk($data, 'filtrar_sql');
                $sql_guardar  = "
                    INSERT INTO registros  (
                        Dia,
                        Hora,
                        Tipo_Acceso,
                        Puerta,
                        Tipo,
                        Tarjeta,
                        Nombres,
                        Apellidos,
                        Documento,
                        Empresa
                    ) VALUES (
                        '$fechaReal',
                        '$hora',
                        '{$data[2]}',
                        '{$data[3]}',
                        '{$data[6]}',
                        '{$data[7]}',
                        '{$data[8]}',
                        '{$data[9]}',
                        '{$data[10]}',
                        '{$data[12]}'
                    )
                ";
                $sql_guardar = mysql_query($sql_guardar);
                if (!$sql_guardar) {
                    die('<div>¡Hubo un problema al momento de importar el archivo! 
                        <br>¡Por favor vuelva a intentarlo!</div>');
                }
                $insertadas++;
            }
            fclose($fp);
            die('<div>¡La importación del archivo se subió satisfactoriamente! (' . $insertadas . ' registros insertados)</div>');
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            die("No ha subido ningún archivo");
            break;
        default:
            die("Se produjo un error en el envío");
    }
}
?><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("submit", "form", function(event) {
        /* Evitamos la propagación del evento para cancelar el envío del formulario */
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Enviamos la petición por XHR */
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>',
            data: new FormData(this),
            type: 'post',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function(resultado) {
            $(".resultado").html(resultado);
        });
    });
});
</script>
<form name="frmSubirArchivo" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border="1" id="TablaFormularioOpaco">
        <tr>
            <td aling="center" id="TituloTablaVerde">Archivo excel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="excel" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Subir Archivo"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<pre class="resultado"></pre>
```

Entre otras cosas he arreglado en el código PHP:

- Agujero de seguridad: el código es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. Recomiendo usar consultas preparadas de [PDO-mysql](http://php.net/pdo-mysql) o bien [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli). Las funciones `mysql_*` fueron marcadas como obsoletas en PHP 5.5 y a partir de PHP 7.0 ya no están disponibles.
- Detección correcta de la recepción de un archivo: `!empty($_FILES['excel'])` no es la forma correcta de saber que se ha enviado un archivo. Ese índice existirá incluso si no se ha enviado un archivo o éste se ha truncado o cortado por tamaño excesivo [u otros problemas](http://php.net/file-upload.errors).
- Comprobación de extensión de archivo mediante expresiones regulares insensibles a mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Comment: Pero con el submit lo saca de la página en la que está y lo manda a otra, **ESO YA ESTÁ Y SUBEN LOS ARCHIVOS** lo que necesito es que se quede en la misma página y suban los archivos.

Comment: No, no envía el formulario porque si ves mi código cancelo la propagación del evento. Copia y pega mi código en un archivo, es auto contenido y funciona autónomamente. Echa un vistazo a su funcionamiento y lee atentamente mis explicaciones de por qué no te funciona correctamente a ti. Lee acerca de la cancelación de eventos aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation y https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: ¿Y qué sigue después del **<pre class="resultado"></pre>**?

Comment: Es donde se muestra el resultado de la petición. En tu código haces referencia a un `#cuerpoPagina` pero no aparece por ningún lado en tu HTML. Sería el equivalente.

Comment: Perdón, acabo de leer que preguntaste "¿Qué sigue?". No sigue nada. Es una prueba de concepto. Si quieres le agrego tu código, pero al no tener el esquema de tu base de datos ni un csv de ejemplo no sabré si funciona.

Comment: Pues en la base de datos los campos están vacíos, pero los campos son: 
 
**Id_Registros Ascendente 1, 
Dia, 
Hora, 
Tipo_Acceso, 
Puerta, 
Tipo, 
Tarjeta, 
Nombres, 
Apellidos, 
Documento, 
Empresa**

Comment: Si en la pregunta agregas el esquema (lo obtienes con un [`SHOW CREATE TABLE registros`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html)) junto con un CSV pequeño de dos o tres líneas (lo mínimo para probar todo) nos facilitarías mucho el trabajo. Gracias.

Comment: Ya está modificado.

Comment: Gracias, me pongo a ello en un momento. [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64018/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-carlos-ortiz).

Comment: ¿Qué tal todo? ¿Probaste el código? Cuando puedas valora mi respuesta positivamente si piensas que te fue de utilidad y márcala como respuesta correcta si así lo es :)