# Guardar archivo en servidor PHP mediante envío AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario con los siguientes archivos. El problema está en que ajax sí reconoce el archivo y lo almacena en la variable `file` pero php no la mueve al servidor:

```
function formSubmit() {
    $('#frminformacion').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var oficina =$('#txtOficina').val()
        var num_oficina =$('#num_oficina').val()
        var turno = $('#NumTurno').val()
        var fecha = $('#register_fecha').val()
        var cronometro = putocronometro;
        var tramite = $('#txtTramite').val()
        var compDom = $('#comDom').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\","")
        var tipoCompDom = document.getElementById("tipoCompDom").options[document.getElementById("tipoCompDom").selectedIndex].value;
        var identi = $('#Identi').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\","")
        var tipoIdenti = document.getElementById("tipoIden").options[document.getElementById("tipoIden").selectedIndex].value;
        var factu =$('#fact').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\","")
        var poliz =$('#pol').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\","")
        var fechaEjemplo = moment(fecha);
        fechaEjemplo = fechaEjemplo.format('DDMMYYYY');
        var carpeta = "T"+turno+num_oficina+fechaEjemplo;

        var file = $("#comDom")[0].files[0];
        //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
        var fileName = file.name;
        //tamaño del archivo
        var fileSize = file.size;
        //obtenemos el tipo de archivo image/png ejemplo
        var fileType = file.type;


        var data2 = 'oficina='+oficina+'&num_oficina='+num_oficina+'&turno='+turno+'&fecha='+fecha+'&cronometro='+cronometro+'&tramite='+tramite+'&fileName='+fileName+'&tipoCompDom='+tipoCompDom+'&identi='+identi+'&tipoIdenti='+tipoIdenti+'&factu='+factu+'&poliz='+poliz+'&carpeta='+carpeta+'&file='+file;

        $.ajax({
            url: "lib/controladores/registrar_tramite.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data2,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(data2);
                if (response.success) {
                    UIkit.notify({
                        message : 'Ocurrio un error, favor de llamar a soporte tecnico'  ,
                        timeout : 3000,
                        pos     : 'top-right',
                        status  : 'danger'
                    });
                }else{
```

Código php:

```
<?php
$carpeta = $_POST['carpeta'];


 mkdir("../../pruebasImagen/$carpeta", 0700);
 $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];


    include '../../config.php';
    $dbserver = DB_SERVER;
    $dbuser = DB_USER;
    $password = DB_PASS;
    $dbname = DB_NAME;


    $database = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $password, $dbname);

    if($database->connect_errno) {
        die("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos");
    }
    (".$valuesInsert.")";
    $jsondata = array();

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"../../pruebasImagen/".$carpeta.$file);



    if($database->query($insertquery)){
        $respuesta->mensaje = "Se guardo correctamente";

    }
    else {
        $respuesta->mensaje = "Ocurrio un error";
    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    $database->close();
?>
```

Formulario HTML:

```html
<form id="frminformacion" enctype= multipart/form-data>
    <div class="md-card-content" style="background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;">
        <div>
            <div class="uk-grid">
            <div class="uk-width-4-10">
              <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled" id="padre_requiered">
                  <label for="txtNumeroTramite">Turno<span class="req"></span></label>
                  <input type="number" readonly="readonly" min="1" id="NumTurno" name="NumTurno" requerido="" data-required-minlength="1"  data-required-maxlength="10" class="md-input" value="001">
                  <span class="md-input-bar "></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-4-10"><div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled" id="padre_requiered">
                    <label for="txtNumeroTramite">Tipo de tramite<span class="req"></span></label>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" min="1" id="txtTramite" name="txtTramite" class="md-input" value="Alta de placas">
                    <span class="md-input-bar "></span>
                </div></div>
                <div class="uk-width-2-10">
                <div class="md-card" id="tiempoTranscurrido" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="md-card-content" style="text-align: center;">
                        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;">
                            <span id="hora_transcurrido">00</span>
                            <span id="minuto_transcurrido">:00</span>
                            <span id="segundo_transcurrido">:00</span>
                        </h2>
                        <span id="hora_inicio" style="display: none;"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-grid">
            <div class="uk-width-4-10">
                <label>Número de Oficina</label>
                <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled">
                        <input type="number" readonly="readonly" id="num_oficina" name="num_oficina" value="<?php echo"$numOficina";?>" class="md-input label-fixed">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-width-4-10">
                <label>Oficina</label>
                <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled">
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  min="1" id="txtOficina" name="txtOficina" requerido="" data-required-minlength="1"  data-required-maxlength="10" class="md-input" value="<?php echo"$oficina";?>">
                    <span class="md-input-bar "></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-width-4-10">
              <label>Fecha y Hora:</label>
              <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled">
                      <input type="datetime" readonly="readonly" id="register_fecha" name="register_fecha" value="<?php echo"$fecha";?>" class="md-input label-fixed">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="md-card">
            <div class="uk-overflow-container">
                <table class="uk-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>
                                Tipo
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Documento
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Adjuntar
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Vista previa
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Estatus
                            </th>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25px !important;">
                            <div class="select">
                            <select name="tipoCompDom" id="tipoCompDom">
                            <option>Comprobante</option>
                            <option value="http://www.cfe.gob.mx/paginas/home.aspx">CFE</option>
                            <option value="http://japac.gob.mx/">JAPAC</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            <td>COMPROBANTE DE DOMICILIO</td>
                            <td> <i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file">attachment
                                                    <input id="comDom" name="comDom" type="file" this accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg"></i></td>
                            <td> <a class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" href="#openModal" >search </a></td>
                             <td>  <i class="material-icons md-icon uk-text-success" id="check1" style="display: none;">done_all</i></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25px !important;">
                            <div class="select">
                            <select name="tipoIden" id="tipoIden">
                            <option>Comprobante</option>
                            <option value="http://www.ine.mx/">INE</option>
                            <option value="https://ciudadano.sinaloa.gob.mx/opciones-tramite/renovacionlicencia">Licencia de manejo</option>
                            <option value="https://www.pasaporte-mexicano.com.mx/sinaloa">Pasaporte</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            <td>IDENTIFICACION</td>
                            <td><i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file">attachment
                                                    <input id="Identi" name="Identi" type="file" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg"></i></td>
                            <td><a class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" href="#openModalIden">search </a></td>
                            <td>  <i class="material-icons md-icon uk-text-success" id="check2" style="display: none;">done_all</i></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25px !important;">
                            <div class="select">
                            <select name="tipoFact" id="tipoFact">
                            <option>Comprobante</option>
                            <option value="http://www.cfe.gob.mx/paginas/home.aspx">CFE</option>
                            <option value="http://japac.gob.mx/">JAPAC</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            <td>FACTURA AUTOMOVIL</td>
                            <td><i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file">attachment
                                                    <input id="fact" name="fact" type="file" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg"></i></td>
                            <td><a class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" href="#openModalFact">search </a></td>
                            <td>  <i class="material-icons md-icon uk-text-success" id="check3" style="display: none;">done_all</i></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25px !important;">
                            <div class="select">
                            <select name="tipoPol" id="tipoPol">
                            <option>Comprobante</option>
                            <option value="http://www.cfe.gob.mx/paginas/home.aspx">CFE</option>
                            <option value="http://japac.gob.mx/">JAPAC</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            <td>POLIZA DE SEGURO</td>
                            <td><i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file">attachment
                                                    <input id="pol" name="pol" type="file" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg"></i></td>
                            <td><a class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" href="#openModalPol">search </a></td>
                            <td>  <i class="material-icons md-icon uk-text-success" id="check4" style="display: none;">done_all</i></td>
                            </tr>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="body_documentos">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>
```

---

```
<form id="frminformacion" enctype= multipart/form-data>
    <div class="md-card-content" style="background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;">
        <div>
            <div class="uk-grid">
            <div class="uk-width-4-10">
              <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled" id="padre_requiered">
                  <label for="txtNumeroTramite">Turno<span class="req"></span></label>
                  <input type="number" readonly="readonly" min="1" id="NumTurno" name="NumTurno" requerido="" data-required-minlength="1"  data-required-maxlength="10" class="md-input" value="001">
                  <span class="md-input-bar "></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-4-10"><div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled" id="padre_requiered">
                    <label for="txtNumeroTramite">Tipo de tramite<span class="req"></span></label>
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" min="1" id="txtTramite" name="txtTramite" class="md-input" value="Alta de placas">
                    <span class="md-input-bar "></span>
                </div></div>
                <div class="uk-width-2-10">
                <div class="md-card" id="tiempoTranscurrido" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="md-card-content" style="text-align: center;">
                        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;">
                            <span id="hora_transcurrido">00</span>
                            <span id="minuto_transcurrido">:00</span>
                            <span id="segundo_transcurrido">:00</span>
                        </h2>
                        <span id="hora_inicio" style="display: none;"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-grid">
            <div class="uk-width-4-10">
                <label>Número de Oficina</label>
                <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled">
                        <input type="number" readonly="readonly" id="num_oficina" name="num_oficina" value="<?php echo"$numOficina";?>" class="md-input label-fixed">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-width-4-10">
                <label>Oficina</label>
                <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled">
                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  min="1" id="txtOficina" name="txtOficina" requerido="" data-required-minlength="1"  data-required-maxlength="10" class="md-input" value="<?php echo"$oficina";?>">
                    <span class="md-input-bar "></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-width-4-10">
              <label>Fecha y Hora:</label>
              <div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-filled">
                      <input type="datetime" readonly="readonly" id="register_fecha" name="register_fecha" value="<?php echo"$fecha";?>" class="md-input label-fixed">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="md-card">
            <div class="uk-overflow-container">
                <table class="uk-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>
                                Tipo
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Documento
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Adjuntar
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Vista previa
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Estatus
                            </th>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25px !important;">
                            <div class="select">
                            <select name="tipoCompDom" id="tipoCompDom">
                            <option>Comprobante</option>
                            <option value="http://www.cfe.gob.mx/paginas/home.aspx">CFE</option>
                            <option value="http://japac.gob.mx/">JAPAC</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            <td>COMPROBANTE DE DOMICILIO</td>
                            <td> <i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file">attachment
                                                    <input id="comDom" name="comDom" type="file" this accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg"></i></td>
                            <td> <a class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" href="#openModal" >search </a></td>
                             <td>  <i class="material-icons md-icon uk-text-success" id="check1" style="display: none;">done_all</i></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25px !important;">
                            <div class="select">
                            <select name="tipoIden" id="tipoIden">
                            <option>Comprobante</option>
                            <option value="http://www.ine.mx/">INE</option>
                            <option value="https://ciudadano.sinaloa.gob.mx/opciones-tramite/renovacionlicencia">Licencia de manejo</option>
                            <option value="https://www.pasaporte-mexicano.com.mx/sinaloa">Pasaporte</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            <td>IDENTIFICACION</td>
                            <td><i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file">attachment
                                                    <input id="Identi" name="Identi" type="file" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg"></i></td>
                            <td><a class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" href="#openModalIden">search </a></td>
                            <td>  <i class="material-icons md-icon uk-text-success" id="check2" style="display: none;">done_all</i></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25px !important;">
                            <div class="select">
                            <select name="tipoFact" id="tipoFact">
                            <option>Comprobante</option>
                            <option value="http://www.cfe.gob.mx/paginas/home.aspx">CFE</option>
                            <option value="http://japac.gob.mx/">JAPAC</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            <td>FACTURA AUTOMOVIL</td>
                            <td><i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file">attachment
                                                    <input id="fact" name="fact" type="file" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg"></i></td>
                            <td><a class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" href="#openModalFact">search </a></td>
                            <td>  <i class="material-icons md-icon uk-text-success" id="check3" style="display: none;">done_all</i></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="width: 25px !important;">
                            <div class="select">
                            <select name="tipoPol" id="tipoPol">
                            <option>Comprobante</option>
                            <option value="http://www.cfe.gob.mx/paginas/home.aspx">CFE</option>
                            <option value="http://japac.gob.mx/">JAPAC</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                             </td>
                            <td>POLIZA DE SEGURO</td>
                            <td><i class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file">attachment
                                                    <input id="pol" name="pol" type="file" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg"></i></td>
                            <td><a class="material-icons uk-text-success md-icon uk-form-file" href="#openModalPol">search </a></td>
                            <td>  <i class="material-icons md-icon uk-text-success" id="check4" style="display: none;">done_all</i></td>
                            </tr>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="body_documentos">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>
```

Comment: tienes una doble comilla de más, en la sentencia `(".$valuesInsert.")";`

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien, lo que quiero hacer es enviar el archivo en var file = $("#comDom")[0].files[0]; a una carpeta en el servidor mediante php

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el HTML del formulario? Si todos los campos están dentro del mismo formulario tengo una solución que reducirá bastante tu código.

Comment: claro que si ...

Comment: Deberías agregar el formulario a tu pregunta editándola, no escribiendo una respuesta. Ahora le echaré un vistazo.

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer una prueba de concepto de tu problema, pero tu código es tan enrevesado (y tienes tantos errores en la jerarquía HTML) que me está consumiendo mucho tiempo. Te envío a una respuesta que hice con un problema similar para que entiendas el problema que estás teniendo y aprendas la manera correcta de enviar datos de formularios a través de XHR: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95608/subir-archivo-en-la-misma-página/95626#95626](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95608/subir-archivo-en-la-misma-página/95626#95626)

Comment: En especial mira la parte en la que uso `data: new FormData(this),`. Carga todos los campos del formulario directamente en `data` sin tener que montar una cadena de caracteres como tú haces. Además, debes tener en cuenta que los archivos no se mandan sólo por indicar el nombre en los datos enviados como estás haciendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo user [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData), agregar la etiqueta `name` a tu `<form>`

```
$("form[name='subirFormulario']").submit(function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
            url: "lib/controladores/registrar_tramite.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            ..............
    });
});
```

La variable `data2` que estas enviando es solo un string, me parece raro que puedas acceder a los datos de esa manera.